# Prove. $\lim_{x\to 2} \frac{x}{1+x} = \frac{2}{3}$ from first principles.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm a student taking a real analysis course and I have been asked the above question. I am new to but slowly figuring out the methods I must take to prove a limit from first principles but I am having trouble in the latter half of the method. So any tips or nudges in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Firstly I fix $\epsilon > 0$ and find $\delta > 0$ such that.

$$0 < |x- 2| < \delta \implies  \bigg| \frac{x}{1+x} - \frac{2}{3}  \bigg|< \epsilon $$

$$ \impliedby \bigg| \frac{x-2}{3(x+1)} \bigg| < \epsilon$$

$$\impliedby \frac{|x-2|}{3|x+1|} < \epsilon$$

I'm having trouble with the next part. I understand you need to pick a value, $n= something$ such that $|x-2| \leq n$, and $\frac{1}{3|x+1|} \geq n $. From here I know you have to pick an $\epsilon$ so. $\delta \leq min(n, ?)$ has the required property.

Sorry for the confusing question. I appreciate your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $|x-2|<1$, then

$-1<x-2<1$, or $2<x+1<4$;

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given.

Choose $\delta =\min (1, 6\epsilon);$

Then

|$x-2|<\delta$ implies

$|\frac{x-2}{3(x+1)}|< \frac{\delta}{3\cdot 2} \le \epsilon.$

Comment: Would it be correct if I use $0<|x-2|<\delta \Rightarrow 2<x<2+\delta$, so $x>2$; so $x+1>3\Rightarrow \frac{1}{3(x+1)} < \frac{1}{9}$ and so choosing $\delta=9\varepsilon$ I conclude? Thanks.

Comment: $0<|x-2|<\delta$ implies $-\delta +2<x<2+\delta$, so $x >2-\delta$, you forgot the $-\delta$. Your thoughts?

Comment: You're right! So it doesn't work, unless I do a reasoning like yours or Jim Haddocc's one. However if $x \to 2^+$ it would work because then I would have $2<x<2+\delta$, right? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes. $x\rightarrow 2^+$, you get $x>2$ as a freebee:).Jim's answer: $x>0$. What this means : $-\delta +2<x$ ; or $\delta <2$, so? All is well when the given $\epsilon$ in his answer is $<2$; But say $\epsilon =3$. There is a problem. Can you see it?

Answer (score 0):

Because $x>0$ in that domain, $\frac{|x-2|}{3|x+1|}<\frac{|x-2|}{3}$. Now chose $\delta$ to be $\epsilon$, and you'll be done. Bounding the denominator was key here.